# Is $\max(|a_{ij}|) \le \| A \|_2$ valid for a complex matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

$\max(|a_{ij}|)$ is a maximal magnitude of the elements of a matrix $A$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$ is a 2-norm.

I've found this inequality for real matrices in the **Matrix Computations**, Gene H. Golub and Charles F. Van Loan (chapter 2.3.2), but without any proof.

I'm wondering, is it also valid for complex matrices?

Can anybody also give some other known bounds for a magnitude of the maximal element of a complex matrix in terms of eigenvalues or singular values? Particulary, I'm intrested in Hermitian matrices.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The formula $a_{ij}=\langle{\bf e}_i, A{\bf e}_j\rangle$ allows to relate matrix elements to "geometric" properties of $A$.

Comment: Yes it must be, since contribution of each other element is non-negative to $\|A\|_2$ and equality would be true if $a_{ij}$ was the only non-zero element.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes.   Golub and Van Loan’s book, as a book on numerical linear algebra, tends to focus on real matrices but this result holds for complex matrices too.

To see this, let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$.  Since the matrix 2-norm is an induced matrix norm, we have that $\left\| A \right\|_2  = \mathop {\max }\limits_{\left\| x \right\|_2  = 1} \left\| {Ax} \right\|_2 $
 or, equivalently, $\left\| A \right\|_2^2  = \mathop {\max}\limits_{\left\| x \right\|_2  = 1} \left\| {Ax} \right\|_2^2$.

Suppose $\left| {a_{r,s} } \right| = \mathop {\max}\limits_{1 \le i \le m \atop 1 \le j \le n} \left| {a_{ij} } \right|$ , where we’re letting $a_{ij}$ denote the element of $A$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column.  Then if we let $x = e_s$, we have that

$\left\| A \right\|_2^2  \ge \left\| {Ae_s } \right\|_2^2  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {\left| {a_{ks} } \right|^2 }  \ge \left| {a_{rs} } \right|^2$

which establishes the result.

As for your other request, recall that the 2-norm of a Hermitian matrix $A$ is equal to the spectral radius $\rho \left( A \right)$ of $A$.  So, from above, we have that

$\mathop {\max}\limits_{1 \le i \le m \atop 1 \le j \le n} \left| {a_{ij} } \right| \le \left\| A \right\|_2  = \rho \left( A \right)$.